# Overlay plots using R with a merged "x" axis and corresponding y axes data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and trying something which I believe is quite doable in R.

This is my dataset. I want to plot the( line plot will do) data with a common merged x axis(time) but corresponding values for Data_1, Data_2 and Data_3 in different coloured lines.

```
Time      Data_1 Time     Data_2  Time    Data_3
08:53:07    2   08:53:07    2   08:53:07    10
08:53:10    5   08:53:10    5   08:53:08    6
08:53:11    2   08:53:11    2   08:53:10    41
08:53:18    6   08:53:18    6   08:53:11    24
08:53:19    1   08:53:19    1   08:53:12    5
08:53:36    9   08:53:36    7   08:53:13    18
08:53:37    1   08:53:37    1   08:53:14    6
08:53:38    8   08:53:38    8   08:53:16    9
08:53:43    1   08:53:43    1   08:53:17    1
08:53:48    5   08:53:48    4   08:53:18    41
08:53:49    4   08:53:49    4   08:53:19    16
08:53:51    1   08:53:51    1   08:53:20    3
08:54:01    3   08:54:01    3   08:53:23    4
08:54:02    1   08:54:02    1   08:53:24    1
08:54:11    3   08:54:11    3   08:53:25    5
08:54:42    14  08:54:42    10  08:53:26    7
```

Any ideas on how this can be done ?

Comment: Tried this -  plot(data_1_csv)
lines(data_1_csv, col="blue")
lines(data_2_csv, col="red")
lines(data_3_csv, col="cyan") . This produces a good plot but it seems it doesn't merge the x axis and hence the data_2 and data_3 are represented wrongly

Comment: If I get what you mean, setting up `xlim` when you call `plot` might be useful. `xlim = c(min(data_1, data_2, data_3), max(data_1, data_2, data_3))`.